# UIView: hide drawing and show it again

Tags: xcode, uiview, hide, draw, layer

I create a view at run time and I use it's `drawRect:` to draw a figure on it. In the next step I add a sublayer with contents of an image to the layer of the view and then I show it. It works. But the figure on the view is still shown below the image. With `view.layer.contents = nil;` before creating the sublayer, the figure on the view is removed. But I need to show it again. With `[view setNeedsDisplay];` (calling `drawRect:`) I can draw it again.

Is there any (easier) way to hide (or cover) this figure and show it again (without removing and redrawing it)? Thanks.

Edit:
I can do this: `layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;` the figure is covered. But the backgroundColor must be transparent. Thanks very much for another ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
view.layer.hidden = YES;
```

If you only want to hide and show a sublayer, you can keep hold of a reference to that sublayer, or find it by looking in `view.layer.sublayers`.

Comment: Thanks. But if the view layer is hidden the sublayer I added is hidden too.

Comment: You can find the sublayer, and then call sublayer.hidden = YES;